# south schemamigration asking for 'one-off value' when trying to mirgate app

Tags: django, models, django-south

okay so I had an app and I wanted to convert it to south (if that's the right terminology). I wanted to do this because I had a model and I did

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

and then I made changes to the model and then it didn't let me syncdb. After doing some changes, I figured out that using south was the solution. SO I put south in my installed apps then I did

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

and got south installed. Then, following the instructions on www.djangopro.com/2011/01/django-database-migration-tool-south-explained/ , I then did

```
manage.py convert_to_south myapp
```

to create the migration file for generation 1 and also to create the migrationhistory entry, which worked. Next, I did

```
manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto
```

and it said

```
 ? The field 'Users.date_of_birth' does not have a default specified, yet is NOT NULL.
 ? Since you are adding this field, you MUST specify a default
 ? value to use for existing rows. Would you like to:
 ?  1. Quit now, and add a default to the field in models.py
 ?  2. Specify a one-off value to use for existing columns now
 ? Please select a choice: 2
 ? Please enter Python code for your one-off default value.
 ? The datetime module is available, so you can do e.g. datetime.date.today()
 >>>
```

What does this mean? Am I doing something wrong? WHat value should I put for the on-off default value?

When I look at this website: south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html ,
I see that when they used the schemamigration --auto and migrate on the app called southtut, it did not ask for the one-off default value at the beginning so I'm guessing I am doing something wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

No everything is fine. You have `Users.date_of_birth` field which does not have default value specified in the model e.g. `default=datetime.now()`, so that is why it is asking to specify the default value for the migration for older entries.

After step two when it says:

```
The datetime module is available, so you can do e.g. datetime.date.today()
```

Just do `datetime.date.today()` and press enter or choose any default date for the `date_of_birth` field.

Comment: Hm okay, so in my Users model (where I added date_of_birth), there is also username (which is also a SlugField, like date_of_birth) and username was already in the Users model. What is the default value for username and where is that specified? Also, what does a default value do exactly? because for username, it is just "username = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)" and that's it, I didn't specify any default value... should I do so?